# Why deleting row in related row boot() is not triggered?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

In my Laravel 5.7 app I have 2 tables Tag, TagDetail(One to One relation) and the second table has image uploaded to storage and image field.
I want using boot method for automatic deletion of related rows and image. As result deleting Tag row related TagDetail is deleted, but image of TagDetail
is not deleted.
I have 2 models and new Tag())->d( is just debugging function 
app/Tag.php :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

use DB;
use App\MyAppModel;
use App\TagDetail;
use App\Http\Traits\funcsTrait;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
use App\Rules\TagUniqueness;


class Tag extends MyAppModel
{
    use funcsTrait;

    protected $table = 'tags';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = false;
    private $votes_tag_type= 'votesTagType';

    public function getTableName() : string
    {
        return $this->table;
    }

    public function getPrimaryKey() : string
    {
        return $this->primaryKey;
    }

    public function tagDetail()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\TagDetail', 'tag_id', 'id');
    }

    protected static function boot() {
        parent::boot();
        static::deleting(function($tag) {
            with (new Tag())->d( '<pre>Tag BOOT $tag::' . $tag->id);
            $relatedTagDetail= $tag->tagDetail();
            if ( !empty($relatedTagDetail) ) {
                $relatedTagDetail->delete();  // I see this is triggered and  relatedTagDetail is deleted 
            }
        });
    }
```

and app/TagDetail.php :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use DB;
use App\MyAppModel;
use App\library\ImagePreviewSize;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use App\Http\Traits\funcsTrait;

class TagDetail extends MyAppModel
{
    use Notifiable;
    use funcsTrait;

    protected $table = 'tag_details';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'tag_id',
        'image',
        'description',
    ];

    public function getTableName() : string
    {
        return $this->table;
    }

    public function getPrimaryKey() : string
    {
        return $this->primaryKey;
    }

    public function Tag()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Tag', 'tag_id');
    }


    protected static function boot() {
        parent::boot();
        static::deleting(function($tagDetail) { // THIS METHOD IS NOT TRIGGERED AT ALL!
            with (new TagDetail())->d( '<pre>TagDetail BOOT $tagDetail::' . $tagDetail->id);

            $tag_detail_image_path= TagDetail::getTagDetailImagePath($tagDetail->id, $tagDetail->image, true);
            with (new TagDetail())->d( '<pre>TagDetail BOOT $tag_detail_image_path::' . $tag_detail_image_path);
            TagDetail::deleteFileByPath($tag_detail_image_path, true);
        });
    }
```

Is something wrong in my models declarations ?

MODIFIED BLOCK # 2:
In my included file public/js/defaultBS41Backend/admin/tag.js I have method:

```
backendTag.prototype.deleteTag = function (id, name) {
    confirmMsg('Do you want to delete "' + name + '" tag with all related data ?', function () {
            var href = this_backend_home_url + "/admin/tag/destroy";

            $.ajax({
                type: "DELETE",
                dataType: "json",
                url: href,
                data: {"id": id, "_token": this_csrf_token},
                success: function (response) {
                    $("#btn_run_search").click()
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alertMsg(error.responseJSON.message, 'Tag deleting error!', 'OK', 'fa fa-exclamation-triangle')
                }
            });

        }
    );

} // backendTag.prototype.deleteTag = function ( id, name ) {
```

and in control :

```
public function destroy(Request $request)
{
    $id  = $request->get('id');
    $tag = MyTag::find($id);

    if ($tag == null) {
        return response()->json(['error_code' => 11, 'message' => 'Tag # "' . $id . '" not found!', 'tag' => null],
            HTTP_RESPONSE_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR); //500
    }

    DB::beginTransaction();
    try {
        $tag->delete();
        DB::commit();

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        DB::rollBack();

        return response()->json(['error_code' => 1, 'message' => $e->getMessage(), 'tag' => null], HTTP_RESPONSE_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

    return response()->json(['error_code' => 0, 'message' => ''], HTTP_RESPONSE_OK_RESOURCE_DELETED); // 204
} //     public function delete(Request $request)
```

and in routes/web.php :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'isVerified'], 'prefix' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin.'], function () {
    Route::delete('/tag/destroy', 'Admin\TagsController@destroy');
    ...
```

Comment: How are you deleting the models?

Comment: Please, look at MODIFIED BLOCK # 2 of original post

Comment: Try replacing `$relatedTagDetail= $tag->tagDetail();` with `$relatedTagDetail= $tag->tagDetail;`.

Comment: Thank you! That was decision, but can you explai me , as I defined method $tag->tagDetail() why have I to call it as property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is `$tag->tagDetail()`: You are using the query builder and deleting the model directly in the database. But the `deleting` event can only be triggered when you retrieve the model first.

Replace `$relatedTagDetail = $tag->tagDetail();` with `$relatedTagDetail= $tag->tagDetail;`.