# Laravel Trigger Model Event on Relation Deleting

Tags: php, laravel, model, eloquent, event-handling

I have 2 events on 2 models.

`User` model:

```
static::deleting(function ($user) {

    $user->team()->deletel();
});
```

`Team` model:

```
static::deleting(function ($team) {
    self::transferMembers($team);
});
```

***Expectation:*** When admin delete a user, the team belongs to that user will be deleted and other users in that team should be transferred to the default team.

***Reality:*** The team was deleted but it didn't trigger the deleting event to transfer members to default team.

Thank you for your helping!

Comment: Can you post the `transferMembers` function?

Comment: You have to use `$user->team->delete();`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53064574/4848587.

Comment: When I try to use `$user->team->deletel();`. I popped up a error like this `Call to undefined method App\Team::deletel()`

Comment: It's `delete()`, not `deletel()`.

Comment: Thank you, you are awesome!!1

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the "deletel" typo, this still won't call your deleting event handler:

```
static::deleting(function ($user) {
    $user->team()->delete();
});
```

The problem is `$user->team()` doesn't make it actually load the team model, it just creates the basis of a database query, than you then turn into a delete query when you add the `->delete()` part.  And so that just does a database query like "DELETE FROM users WHERE id=__".

To make it delete while calling any event handlers on the model, you have to do this instead:

```
static::deleting(function ($user) {
    $user->team->delete();
});
```

The subtle difference is that it's `$user->team` instead of `$user->team()`.  That makes it load the actual model into memory, and then it calls the delete method on it.

Understanding the difference between those two ways of using an Eloquent relationship is very important to understand to use Eloquent correctly.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for HasMany relationsihps, like `$user->teams->delete` as it will return a collection of models.

Comment: If a user can have many teams, you're right that `$user->teams->delete()` won't work at all and will just give you an error because `$user->teams` is the collection of models so calling `delete()` on a collection does nothing. But what does work is you can delete them all with `$user->teams()->delete()` (with the parenthesis on `teams()`), and that would delete all the teams at once with a "DELETE" database query. Those parenthesis on teams is the difference between fetching the models, vs. getting the database builder query that you can build on.

Comment: Yes, sure. In my case I did: `$user->teams->each(function ($team) { $team->delete() });` Which will trigger delete model event